# ¿Como agrupar elementos identicos de una columna de un DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Cuento con un DataFrame y quiero agrupar las filas que se encuentran en una misma columna dependiendo de la similitud de los elementos de la columna, es decir, por ejemplo tengo el siguiente DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    [10009, "CR 89 92-32","125"], 
                    [10007, "AV 33 25","150"],
                    [10008, "CLL 50 40-23","150"],
                    [10007, "CLL 45 38-60","150"],
                    [10010, "CR 80 50-35","-220"],
                    [10009, "CR 89 92-3","-275"],
                    [10011, "AV 33 26","500"]]),
                   columns=['Código', 'Dirección', 'valor'])
```

Entonces podemos notar que en la columna Dirección la primer y la penultima fila son muy parecidas en los valores CR 89 92-3 y CR 89 92-32 al igual que la segunda y la ultima fila. La idea y requerimiento que tengo es el de agrupar estas filas a pesar de que tengan una pequeña variación en un caracter y obtener algo asi:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    [10009, "CR 89 92-32","125"],
                    [10009, "CR 89 92-3","-275"], 
                    [10007, "AV 33 25","150"],
                    [10007, "CR 80 50-35","-220"],
                    [10008, "CLL 50 40-23","150"],
                    [10021, "CLL 45 38-60","150"],
                    [10011, "AV 33 26","500"]]),
                   columns=['Código', 'Dirección', 'valor'])
```

Pense intentar con:

`df_aux = df.groupby('Dirección')`. Pero con las pequeñas variaciones no lograra agrupar lo que deseo. Por otro lado sé que hay una libreria llamada difflib pero no sé si pueda enlazarla con Pandas.
Gracias

Comment: lo que muestras no es un dataframe agrupado, es un dataframe ordenado segun lo que quisiste. No estoy seguro que se pueda nativamente con pandas (tal vez si, pero de forma "rara")

Comment: Tienes razón, aunque la idea si seria agrupar estos y por otro lado también he consultado y no encuentro una forma nativa de pandas.

Comment: Se me ocurre una forma pero no se que tan eficiente sea

Comment: Podrías compartirla?, me seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurrió 2 formas de hacerlo sin embargo cada una da un resultado distinto por que he aplicado distintos algoritmos y lógica a cada solción, la que he visto que da mejor resultado es la segunda. Para el desarrollo de cada  una de las funciones he utilizado una que otra sintaxis un poco "avanzada" como por ejemplo las comprensiones de listas, operadores ternarios,uso de `zip()`

### Primera froma

Para esta primera código imlemente un algoritmo que se base en el número de coincidencias caracter por caracter donde se toma la primera fila del daaframe, se descomene su valor en una lista (conformada por todos los caracteres menos los vacios). Posteriormente procedemos a iterar en las filas del DataFrame y verificar si el elemento (caracter) se encuentra en nuestra lista, en caso se encuentre colocamos 1 y caso contrario 0, con esto creamos una lista de 1s y 0s para posteriormente sumar y con eso obtendremos el numero de elementos en común.

```py
def my_groupby(df:pd.DataFrame, by:str=None):
    if not by: return df #retornamos todo normal en caso no se especifique 
    df2 = df.copy() #realizamos copia de la dataframe
    df2["new_index_by"] = [[0,0]]*len(df2) #creamos una nueva columna y la llenamos con listas [0,0]

    for dato,i in zip(df2[by].iloc[:-1], df2.index[:-1]): #iteramos en el df y sus indices
        n = [c.lower() for c in dato if c.strip()] #creamos la lista de caracteres

        # recorremos nuevamente el dataframe para evaluar cada dato
        for other,i2 in zip(df2[by].iloc[i+1:], df2.index[i+1:]): 
            n2 = sum([( 1 if c in n else 0) for c in other if c.strip()]) #creamos lista de 1s y 0s
            # asignamos el valor segun corresponda
            df2["new_index_by"][i2] = [i,n2] if n2>=df2["new_index_by"][i2][1] else df2["new_index_by"][i2]
    # retornamos el dataframe ordenado en base a la nueva columna y eliinamos esa columna
    return df2.sort_values(by="new_index_by").drop(columns="new_index_by")
```

El truco de todo esto está en el `if/else` donde asignamos el valor, este valor va a ser una lista de 2 elementos. El primer elemento indica el indice del elemento con el que más concuerda (mayor coincidencia o similitud) y el segundo elemento indica el número de caracteres que coinciden. Dado que el DataFrame se itera varias veces puede que una fila, por ejemplo la 1, sea similar a la fila 2 pero que la fila 2 tenga mayor similitud con la fila 5 y para este caso está el `if` donde se cambia esa lista asignada por una nueva solo si el número de similitud es mayor.

#### Resultado

Para tu DataFrame el resulado es el siguiente. Hacemos `print(my_groupby(df,"Dirección"))`

|  | Código | Dirección | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10009 | CR 89 92-32 | 125 |
| 1 | 10007 | AV 33 25 | 150 |
| 5 | 10009 | CR 89 92-3 | -275 |
| 2 | 10008 | CLL 50 40-23 | 150 |
| 3 | 10007 | CLL 45 38-60 | 150 |
| 4 | 10010 | CR 80 50-35 | -220 |
| 6 | 10011 | AV 33 26 | 500 |

### Segunda forma

Para esta segunda se me ocurrió usar expresiones regulares ya que así podremos evaluar de mejor forma si hay coincidencias, pero el problema con el que me enfrenté fue el hecho de hacer una expresión regular buena y efitar la menor cantidad de falsos positivos y hacer que sea variable, es decir, que para cada fila se genere una nueva expresión regular. Para tratar de solventar este problema decidí crear una funcion que se encarge de generar una expresión reglar según el valor de la fila y priorizando las letras, ya que me he dado cuenta que el anterior método fallaba por que hay más números que letras y esto hace que haya mayor probabilidad de que `"123422"` coincida con `"HO LA 4 23-21"`.

```py
def generate_regex(cadena):
    reg = cadena
    for c in cadena: #iteramos en la cadena
        if c.isnumeric(): #en caso sea un número
            reg = reg.replace(c,".") #reemplazamos por un punto
    #puedes reemplazar todo lo anterior por:
    # reg = "".join(("." if c.isnumeric() else c) for c in cadena)
    reg = re.sub("\.+",".+",reg) #si hay varios puntos quitamos todos y solo dejamos uno
    return reg #retornamos la expresión regular
```

Esto lo que hace es reemplazar los números de la cadena por un punto que en una expresión regular significa que coincide contodos los caracteres. Mi idea original era reemplazar los números por `\d`, los espacios por `\s` y escapar los caracteres especiales `()*$[].\` pero tuve unos incovenientes con el caracter de escape (`\`) y mejor decidí hacer algo simple (puedes implementar lo que dije y seguro tendrás una expresión regular más robusta)

Una vez teniendo eso ya podemos hacer nuestra función para hallar la similitud. Es casi lo mismo a la anterior función, solo cambia loque hay dentro del segundo ciclo `for`

```py
def my_groupby_regex(df:pd.DataFrame, by=None, regex=None):
    if not by: return df
    df2 = df.copy()

    df2["new_index_by"] = df.index #creamos una nueva columna con los valores de los indices

    for dato,i in zip(df2[by].iloc[:-1], df2.index[:-1]):
        reg = re.compile(regex) if regex else re.compile(generate_regex(dato)) #compilamos  la expresión regular

        for other,i2 in zip(df2[by].iloc[i+1:], df2.index[i+1:]):
            if reg.match(other):#si hay coincidencia
                if i < i2: # si la fila en la que estamos es mayor a la del ciclo anterior
                    # colocamos en esta fila lo mismo que tiene la fila que estamos comparando(primer bucle)
                    df2.loc[i2,"new_index_by"] = df2.loc[i,"new_index_by"]
                else:
                    df2.loc[i2,"new_index_by"] = i #colocamos el indice del bucle anterior
    # retornamos el dataframe ordenado y eliminamos la columna que creamos
    return df2.sort_values(by="new_index_by").drop(columns="new_index_by")
```

#### Resultado

Para este caso el resultado ya es un poco más razonable. Hacemos `print(my_groupby_regex(df,"Dirección"))`

|  | Código | Dirección | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10009 | CR 89 92-32 | 125 |
| 4 | 10010 | CR 80 50-35 | -220 |
| 5 | 10009 | CR 89 92-3 | -275 |
| 1 | 10007 | AV 33 25 | 150 |
| 6 | 10011 | AV 33 26 | 500 |
| 2 | 10008 | CLL 50 40-23 | 150 |
| 3 | 10007 | CLL 45 38-60 | 150 |

Cabe aclarar que lo que se hace aquí **no** es ningún tipo de agrupación, más  bien es un tipo de ordenamiento por similitud (algo similiar a ordenar colores),he utilizado el termino "groupby" en mis funciones solo por que me había olvidado de cambiarlo, en realidad debería de ser "orderby" ya que en ningún momento se realiza un agrupamiento de datos solo se coloca en orden (uno debajo de otro) los datos que sean similares.

### Bonus

He notado que este ordenamiento se realiza basicamente de acuerdo a las primeras letras del conenido de la columna sin tener mucha precedencia en el resto, es como si todos los datos que comienzan con `CR` pertenezcan a la fábrica "CR" y el número sea algo como identificador o algo por el estilo. Todo esto lo estoy presuponiendo y puede que me equivoque, pero en caso quieras hacer un agrupamiento donde se tome en cuenta estas primeras letras puedes hacer lo siguiente que es mucho más corto.

```py
# se separa las palabras del stringy se toma el primer elemento
df_final = df.sort_values(by="Dirección", key= lambda x: [c.split()[0] for c in x], ascending=False)
print(df_final)
#en este caso se ordena alfabeticamente según laletra
```

Teniendo como resultado:

|  | Código | Dirección | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10009 | CR 89 92-32 | 125 |
| 4 | 10010 | CR 80 50-35 | -220 |
| 5 | 10009 | CR 89 92-3 | -275 |
| 2 | 10008 | CLL 50 40-23 | 150 |
| 3 | 10007 | CLL 45 38-60 | 150 |
| 1 | 10007 | AV 33 25 | 150 |
| 6 | 10011 | AV 33 26 | 500 |